# Is $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{|(1-\frac{n p_n}{n})|^{n-k}- e^{- \lambda}|}{k!}=0$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

Does anybody know whether this limit here is zero, if we assume that
$np_n \to \lambda$ for $n \to \infty$?

$$
\mbox{So, do we have}\quad
\lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{k=0}^{n}{1 \over k!}\,
\left\vert\,\left(1 - {np_n \over n}\right)^{n-k}
-{\rm e}^{-\lambda}\,\right\vert\ =\ 0\quad {\large ?}
$$
One thing that came to my mind was that if you split at a particular $k_0$, then for $k>k_0$ the $k!$ in the denominator may be dominating this, as the nominator is bounded and for $k<k_0$ the convergence of the nominator for small $k$ to zero could make this sum small. But I don't know whether this can be useful.

If anything is unclear, please let me know.

Comment: Where would something like this come from? Did you intend $e^{-\lambda k}$ instead?

Comment: from probability theory...no, it is meant this way.

Comment: You have $\frac{n p_n}{n}$. What do you really mean?

Comment: I mean it that way. I have just written this that way in order to show the similarity between this sequence and the exponential term. (1-x/n)^n -> e^(-x)